# Unable to Determine why Frame Too Large For GIF Govips

Tags: go, gif, image-resizing, vips

I am trying to resize the following [GIF](https://gasfn25jo7ihtd6hweq44q3lymldirlacwdy5cjadirnjuhpomiq.arweave.net/MCRW66l30HmPx7EhzkNrwxY0RWAVh46JIBoi1NDvcxE)

Original Dimensions are: 1270 x 1270 and a total of 149 Pages

I am resizing to the following Dimensions:

1. 250 x 250 (**Successful**)
2. 500 x 500 (**Successful**)
3. 750 x 750 (**Unsuccessful**)

It fails for the last case and after some digging I found that the limits are set in [libvips](https://github.com/libvips/libvips/blob/v8.13.0/libvips/foreign/cgifsave.c#L715-L726). I am not able to conclude how the dimensions are violating the constraints.

Constraints Being:

```
if( (guint64) frame_rect.width * frame_rect.height > INT_MAX / 4 || 
        frame_rect.width > 65535 || 
        frame_rect.height > 65535 ) {
        vips_error( class->nickname, "%s", _( "frame too large" ) );
        return( -1 );
    }
```

Currently I have the latest govips(v2.11.0) and vips(8.13.3) versions installed.

I tried different sizes and it is working till 740 x 740. I tried to change the Export Params but am unable to figure the math behind why the frame is too large.

Comment: Question asked and answered here: https://github.com/libvips/libvips/issues/3181

Comment: Hrishikesh, please DO NOT cross post questions. Ask in one place. You are making unnecessary extra work for volunteer maintainers.